# Binding to an empty/blank row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an editable datagrid whose CanUserAddRows property is set to true.

I want to put "*" in the blank row's row header. Currently I'm trying to do it by a style trigger in its XAML code but I don't know where I should bind it.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get the most out of this website, please take a moment to read through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages. In particular, please read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page which will explain why you were asked to post some code and why your question has remained unanswered. Users of this site tend to prefer questions that show that question authors have made a good attempt at their problem.